# How to create a Win7 read-only boot drive?

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, freeze

Long story short - I have Win7 installed on SSD which is my primary boot disk C: drive. I have another 2TB SATA IDE HDD as the D: drive which stores most of my programs and all my data.

So far so good until the PC would have freezed on occassions that I have my Windows Media Player playing movies. By freezed I mean really 'freezed' - no response to Ctrl-Alt-Delete or press the switch on the box which normally you can reboot the PC. I actually need to unplug and plug the power supply in order to get the computer back.

The most annoying part comes after I switch on the PC - it doesn't recognize the SSD and saying that no valid boot device. It will come back after I retried a number of times (number varies) and prompted the Windows re-boot menu (the one you have after you didn't shut down Windows normally).

I don't know for exactly what's going on. One thing I noticed is it fails every time I was using Windows Media Player or my place has an unexpected power failure (this happened once).

Another annoying thing is I am not able to reproduce the problem at will - it won't freeze every time I use Windows Media Player.

Suppose SSD shouldn't subject to massive write (update/delete) operations. I am thinking how I can create a booting C: drive with all the pagefiles, user temp data and temporary internet files, etc... moved to D: drive.

Is that possible? How should I tackle it?

Comment: This normally occurs because of ram, the cpu over heating, or possibly a windows glitch in the media player (unlikely), its pretty much impossible to say unless you can reproduce the problem constantly. Now as far as your hard drive problem goes, focus on your sata connection setup, depending on your mobo you might be required to set it up a certain way for the SSD to constantly boot first. Aside from that, I'd upgrade the BIOS, your current version might have a glitch.

Comment: Also, your trying to figure out work arounds instead of getting at the core problem of why you're having to restart x number of times to get your SSD to recognize, this is not normal, i think you should reword your question to fix this problem first.

Comment: Try updating your SSD firmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1 Moving the swap file.
[image]

Part 2 Moving Temporary Internet Files

[image]

Part 3 Temp folder locations

[image]